# How to reorder the Search Result?

Tags: php, mysql, search

When I search a word "apple" the script is showing the result in the following order:

(1) appletree
(2) juiceapple
(3) apple

But I want to reorder the search result in the following order:

(1) apple
(2) appletree
(3) juiceapple

As you can see the above order is exactly what I want in which the result is showing according to the searched term which was "apple"

```
//get date
$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];

if (!$button)
   echo "Please fill out the form";
else
{
    if (strlen($search)<=2)
   echo "The item you searched for was to small";
    else
   {
     echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'>";

     //connect to database

     mysql_connect('localhost','wnumber','passowrd');
     mysql_select_db('wnumber');


 //explode search term
           $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);
           foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($search_each, 0, 4));
    //construct query
    $x++;
    if ($x==1) $construct .= "keywords LIKE '$str%'";
    else       $construct .= " OR keywords LIKE '$str%'";
}




     //echo out construct
    $construct = "SELECT * FROM word WHERE $construct";
    $run = mysql_query($construct);
     $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

     if ($foundnum==0)
        echo "No results found.";
     else
     {

       echo "$foundnum results found.<p><hr size='1'>";

       while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
       {


        //get data
       $meaning = $runrows['meaning'];
       $keywords = $runrows['keywords'];

        echo "<b>$keywords</b><br>
       <b>$meaning</b><br>

       }

     }



    }
}
```

Comment: using LIKE 'apple%' did not match juiceapple, but '%apple%' will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than Ascending if your concern about the length means try `LENGTH()`

```
$construct = "SELECT * FROM word WHERE $construct order by LENGTH(`keywords`)
```

Comment: but if `keywords` column contains multiple keywords, this will show rows that have the less keywords (the shortest value of keyword column) first

Answer (score 2):

use order by asc

> $construct = "SELECT * FROM word WHERE $construct ORDER BY [Field Name from which you want ascend your search ] ASC";

Comment: i replace the line but page show error Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 59

Comment: @user1835767 try... $con = mysql_connect('localhost','wnumber','passowrd');
     
mysql_select_db('wnumber', $con);

instead of 


mysql_connect('localhost','wnumber','passowrd');
     
mysql_select_db('wnumber');

Comment: @user1835767 the line which added to yours is from my own query and it works fine here. What value did u keep in **[Field Name from which you want ascend your search ]**

Answer (score 2):

try

ORDER BY keyword Asc

To get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

use `ORDER BY keywords ASC` it will give you appropriate result as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have multiple **keywords** for every row. You are getting all these results because you are searching for any words that contains word `apple`.

To get exact results first, and then only results that contain the word, do it like this:

1. search for **results that match** exactly the word "apple"
2. search for any **results that contains** word "apple"

As you have multiple keywords for every row, you can't use `=` operator. But you must use some `separator` in your table to separate the keywords from each other. Let's assume its "" (whitespace).

So if your table and column "keywords" looks like this for example

```
| id | name  | keywords |
| 1  | apple | apple fruit sweet |
```

You can search for results like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
WHERE
 keywords LIKE "% $keyword %" /* Notice whitespaces around the variable */
 OR
 keywords LIKE "$keyword %" /* This is for keywords that arent separated from left */
 OR
 keywords LIKE "% $keyword" /* This is for keywords that arent separated from right */

UNION DISTINCT /* Distinct is there because we want to show every result just once */

SELECT * FROM table t1
WHERE
 keywords LIKE "%$keyword%"
```

PS: separator could be any string or character, it doesnt have to be whitespace